# Spring + Hibernate implementation in multi-modules

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, applicationcontext, multi-module

My problem - for the study Spring I write a not great application composed of several modules (multimoduls).

```
 module1
    src
      entity
      dao
    resource
        spring-config.xml ---> This is DataSource, SessionFactory, TransactionManager
 module2
    src
      entity
      dao
    resource
        spring-config.xml ---> This is DataSource, SessionFactory, TransactionManager
 service1
     src
       service_for_module1
     resource
       spring-config.xml ---> Initialization bean Service1 (used for module1)
 service2
     src
       service_for_module2
     resource
       spring-config.xml ---> Initialization bean Service2 (used for module2)
  web
    src
      ManagerBeanForJSF
    web
      pages
      WEB-INF
        spring 
            spring-config.xml ---> Import all spring config from modules
```

I have exception **org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException**.
When I did not have module2 - all worked successfully. Error associated with duplication of SessionFactory and TransactionManager?
Can you give an example of application in Spring composed of several modules.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a maven project and post the poms so we can clearly see the dependencies between the projects.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is a bit incomplete I can only guess you're using maven. Right? Anyway, when using Spring you should definitely, as you already wrote yourself, define the infrastructural part in one common module. Spring provides the possibility to include other context files. Even with wildcards. So you could define one singular main context file that loads those of all others in one go. The best is to have some sort of naming conventions, so that each module can easily contribute its context files.

Comment: I have to make the file spring-config.xml to Web module and clean spring-config to module1 and module2? Move beans DataSource and SessionFactory and TransactionManager to spring-config to Web-module?

Comment: @ddrad Well, yes, that should work. I'd recommend putting productive infrastructural spring definitions into the Web module. For tests, rather duplicate the testing infrastructure into a common module that all other modules can "see".